# Fob not working: 433MHz RF signals not detected

Tags: hat, radio

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.2 with an Adafruit Hat-board, running Python 3.9.2. I'm trying to set up a fob to act as a remote control, but it seems that I'm unable to receive a signal.  I am using the https://github.com/milaq/rpi-rf library and testing out the scripts there.  I have tried 4 different receivers connected to different pins.  To test I am running the sample script and specifying the GPIO pin, e.g.

```
./rpi-rf_receive -g 17
```

I sometimes pick up some signals there (possibly from random interference?), nothing is received when I click buttons on my fobs.

I've tried out [piscope](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html)... it is usually completely flat, but sometimes (!) it shows some signals on the relevant GPIO pin.

I'm feeling very stuck and I'm not sure how proceed with debugging this functionality.  I tried some of the compiled examples from https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html, but I couldn't verify any reception with those either.

Some questions:

1. Can I still use GPIO pins with the Adafruit Hat-board installed? (I need it to drive an LED matrix)
2. Are the numbers printed on the Adafruit Hat-board the GPIO numbers?  Or are they the "original" pin numbers?  Most scripts seem to want the GPIO number, but it's confusing because the original pin number and the GPIO number are not the same.
3. Is there a better way to debug this?

Comment: Are your fobs actually sending anything on 433MHz? Is the signal they send compatible with the receiver (frequency is not the only consideration) What is an "Adafruit Hat board"? Adafruit sell many Pi hats, can't find one called "Board". In the example command, you use `-g 17` - I take it you've connected to **physical** pin 11 when you do that? Also, what are the 4 RF receivers you've used?

Comment: "Are the numbers printed on the (unspecified) Adafruit Hat-board the GPIO numbers?" surely it can't be that hard to work out which pins are connected to the header.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the hat board was the issue -- I believe it's this board: [Adafruit RGB Matrix HAT + RTC for Raspberry Pi - Mini Kit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2345). When I disconnected the hat board and tried connecting the RF receivers to the "naked" Raspberry Pi, I was able to get the scripts to work, so it seems like there's an incompatibility there.